# Constructor of NewFeedModel cannot be applied to given types

Tags: constructor

Constructor of NewFeedModel cannot be applied to given types:

```
NewFeedModel newFeedModel = new NewFeedModel();
```

`NewFeedModel()` <<~~ this one get error

How can I modify it?

```
 //This method will parse json data
    private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            //Creating the newFeedModel object
            NewFeedModel newFeedModel = new NewFeedModel();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                //Getting json
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                //Adding data to the newFeedModel object
                newFeedModel.setFeedPostImageURL(json.getString(FeedConfig.TAG_FeedPostPhoto));
                newFeedModel.setFeedInfo(json.getString(FeedConfig.TAG_FeedInfo));
                newFeedModel.setFeedPostName(json.getString(FeedConfig.TAG_FeedPostName));
                newFeedModel.setFeedimageURL(json.getString(FeedConfig.TAG_FeedMediaPhoto_URL));
                newFeedModel.setFeedGroupName(json.getString(FeedConfig.TAG_FeedGroupName));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Adding the newFeedModel object to the list
            listNewFeedModel.add(newFeedModel);
        }

        //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

```
public class NewFeedModel {
    private String FeedPostImageURL;
    private String FeedPostName;
    private String FeedGroupName;
    private String FeedInfo;
    private String FeedimageURL;

    public NewFeedModel(String feedPostImageURL, String feedPostName, String feedGroupName, String feedInfo, String feedimageURL) {
        this.FeedPostImageURL = feedPostImageURL;
        this.FeedPostName = feedPostName;
        this.FeedGroupName = feedGroupName;
        this.FeedInfo = feedInfo;
        this.FeedimageURL = feedimageURL;
    }

    public String getFeedPostImageURL() {
        return FeedPostImageURL;
    }

    public void setFeedPostImageURL(String feedPostImageURL) {
        this.FeedPostImageURL = feedPostImageURL;
    }

    public String getFeedPostName() {
        return FeedPostName;
    }

    public void setFeedPostName(String feedPostName) {
        this.FeedPostName = feedPostName;
    }

    public String getFeedGroupName() {
        return FeedGroupName;
    }

    public void setFeedGroupName(String feedGroupName) {
        this.FeedGroupName = feedGroupName;
    }

    public String getFeedInfo() {
        return FeedInfo;
    }

    public void setFeedInfo(String feedInfo) {
        this.FeedInfo = feedInfo;
    }

    public String getFeedimageURL() {
        return FeedimageURL;
    }

    public void setFeedimageURL(String feedimageURL) {
        this.FeedimageURL = feedimageURL;
    }
}
```

where miss string?

I try to more method, still cannot solve it.
I try to more method, still cannot solve it.
I try to more method, still cannot solve it.
I try to more method, still cannot solve it.
I try to more method, still cannot solve it.

Comment: Your `NewFeedModel` class does not have default constructor which is with empty parameter. Try to add default contructor as well  `public NewFeedModel (){ }`

Answer (score 1):

Your `NewFeedModel` has constructor with parameters. There is no default constructor. You should initialize it as

`NewFeedModel newFeedModel = new NewFeedModel("someString","someString","someString","someString","someString");`